# How to mock sort function with Sinon

Tags: typescript, sinon-chai

I am writing a unit test for a Repository function using sinon. The function uses sort and when I run the test, the test fails with the error sort is undefined.

Here is my code:

Repository:

```
    async findEventsByTriggerDate(
        eventDatetime: Date
    ): Promise<EventDocument[]> {
        if (eventDatetime) {
            const eventArray = await this.eventModel
                .find({ triggerEventDate: { $lte: eventDatetime } })
                .sort({ createdAt: 1 })
                .lean()
                .exec();

            return eventArray;
        }
    }
```

Unit Test:

```
  describe("getEvents", () => {
    it("should retrieve all events", async () => {
      const stub = sinon.stub(EventModel, "find").returns(stubValue);
      const result = await eventRepository.findEventsByTriggerDate(testDate);

      expect(stub.calledOnce).to.be.true;
      expect(result.createdAt).to.equal(stubValue.createdAt);
    });
  });
```

I think I need to have some way to make sort, lean recognizable for the unit test to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.